# InterstitialAd' does not contain a definition for 'OnAdLeavingApplication' and no accessible extension method

Tags: sdk, admob

InterstitialAd' does not contain a definition for 'OnAdLeavingApplication' and no accessible extension method 'OnAdLeavingApplication' accepting a first argument of type 'InterstitialAd' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Anyone tell me how i can resolve this error in admob new ads sdk becuase new ads sdk 6.0.1 creating this error in call backs

Answer (score 0):

```
this.interstitial.LoadAd(request);
```

use this line

or this simple one: https://developers.google.com/admob/unity/interstitial

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.